# Date format on query different from date format in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

I wrote a SQL query to have the results from 2016 Apr 01 to 2016 May 01.
When I wrote:

```
where a.DateIntervention >= '2016-04-01'
and a.DateIntervention < '2016-05-01'
```

I obtain the results from `2016 Jan 04 00:00:00.000`, so it is reading my dates as ydm, although the results show the date format as ymd `(2016-01-04 00:00:00.000)`

And when I ask the system about the date format it tells me it is dmy (!)

How to change this setting so that I can write my queries like ymd and continue obtaining the results like ymd?

Comment: ... I think this is the first time I've heard of somebody actually being hit by this quirk of the server.  Is the server (or you) in... France, or have a French language set, I think it was?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Do you have a reference to this error? This can be a nasty bug. DISCLAIMER: I _HATE_ date/times.

Comment: @Shawn - One of [Aaron Bertrand's Bad Habits posts](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).  Which, again, is why date/time stuff should be referenced as actual date/time types.  Not that databases are great for most date/time stuff anyways, since most of them don't deal with time zones properly, if at all (fairly reasonable, given the problems with serializing local times, but annoying nonetheless).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes, in fact I am in Canada and the language is set to French, (Although, nothing is shown in french..)

Comment: @Gdiaz - date/time formatting settings are usually part of the _locale_, which is a combination location/language pair, essentially (ie, `en_US` - English language, US country).  So it could just be that you're only inheriting the country/location part, which is setting the relevant flag.  Of course, this only affects error/information messages, not anything stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you don't need to.  If you drop the hyphens then the strings will be interpreted using YYYYMMDD:

```
where a.DateIntervention >= '20160401' and a.DateIntervention < '20160501'
```

I prefer the hyphens because they are more readable, accepted in most databases, and generally work in SQL Server.  There are particular settings where they don't work, but `'YYYYMMDD'` is always interpreted as a date.

I should add, you *can* throw in a `cast()`/`convert()` if you like:

```
where a.DateIntervention >= cast('20160401' as date) and
      a.DateIntervention < cast('20160501' as date)
```

Comment: Thanks! Like this (20160401) I obtain the whole month and not only one day!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way for the query to realize "I was supplied a YMD date, I should output dates as YMD too.".

In theory you could call `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`, but I mislike that because it might affect something farther down the line you don't know about.

If you want an explicit formatting/parsing style during conversion (which is almost always a good idea), you need to explicitly convert it, and [supply the style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

```
-- 126 is hyphenated, but has extra parts if something other than date is used
CONVERT(DATE, '2017-07-28', 126)
```

Of course, the best option is to supply the parameter as an actual `DATE` type, and get output the same way, which saves you from converting back and forth to a string type, and avoids the formatting problem.  This may not be available in a cases, however (like ad hoc queries).